# Add Server in Eclipse via Command line? (Windows)

Tags: eclipse, windows, server, puppet, chocolatey

I would like to set up the laptops of our java developers in a more automated way.
I installed eclipse and all necessary plugins and checked out the repository via Puppet+Chocolatey. An IBM Websphere Liberty Profile for testing the application is running in a virtual machine on the laptops as well.

**Is there any way to add a new server in Eclipse via the command line? Or connect to an existing one? Using for example eclipsec.exe?**

I already fought my way through the documentation but without success. (http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Have anyone of you experience with this kind of problem?

Cheers,
Stephan

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No unfortunately not. If you find a solution by yourself, please feel free to share it